# Write failed: Broken pipe from OSX to AWS

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mac-osx, amazon-web-services

I'm ssh-ing into my AWS box (which is Ubuntu 12.04.2) from my local OSX machine. After successfully ssh-ing into the box using the following command:

ssh -i my-cert.pem ubuntu@

I find that after a minute or so of inactivity, the connection dies and I eventually get thrown back out to my OSX terminal with the message: Write failed: Broken pipe

I've tried adding 'KeepAlive yes' and 'ClientAliveInterval 60' in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the Ubuntu box but still seem to get the same issue.

Comment: What is the TMOUT value on the AWS box? Does the network do anything to close the connection? Does it work the same from other systems as from the OSX box?

Answer (score 0):

You must measure the idle time before you get thrown out more exactly, and set the Interval below that.